# Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop - Not even Ctrl+Alt+F1/6 working

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia, login

Ok, *don't judge this as a duplicate question*, please read through the whole thing.

I have read the other thread and the solution is usually to press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and then start working on the problem. Read my problem and you will see that solution does not fit me.

This is my problem:
Somewhere during installation of Nvidia Drivers (or afterwards), I restarted the PC and now I can not login to the system anymore.

Everything boots up as normal until I am prompted with the `Ubuntu login page`. I enter my password, the screen gets black and soon after that the login screen comes back.
Now to the much bigger problem, I can not even use `Ctrl+Alt+F1 (to F6)` to get a tty console. Pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F1` just takes me to a black screen and nothing happens, the only combination which works in `Ctrl+Alt+F7` which takes me back to the login screen.

I can use the guest user to enter the system but I have no access privileges to do anything useful there and I still get the same issue if I press `Ctrl+Alt+F1`.

What can I do at this point? (I spent hours setting up that system)

Answer (score 1):

Follow instructions bellow
1- Use a live Linux cd and `chroot` to your Ubuntu.
2- Remove `nvidia driver` using `apt-get purge`.(`apt-get purge nvidia-*`)
3- Reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` package.

Comment: tried this. did not help.

Comment: try reconfigure `lightdm` using `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: And you can try using `modprobe nouveau`, maybe it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get into the grub2 menu? Have you tried safe mode

[How would I boot into the Ubuntu and Windows recovery modes if I removed the options to do so from the Grub menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135509/how-would-i-boot-into-the-ubuntu-and-windows-recovery-modes-if-i-removed-the-opt)

I just read your edit after I gave the answer, your ability to use the guest login points to an error with your account / password / privileges did you use an old /home directory or an old /etc/passwd file?

Not being able to use terminals 1-6 could be graphic related (wrong mode)
Did you read the Messages behind the splash-screen (ESC).
Are you as a guest privileged enough to read /var/log ?

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem in my PC,I tried everything. (delete xauthority and ICEauthority files, restart lightm, reconfigure lightdm..). Nothing works.

so, I suggest you to refresh your ubuntu. I think that's the only solution for login loop...

Answer (score 0):

I just has this issue. What worked for me was doing the ALT+CTRL+F3 and in there, ,log in, and re-install ubuntu-desktop package.

Not sure what it did.. But it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I went into recovery mode (in gnub on advanced options), enabled network, went into root shell and installed gdm.