# How to enter windows advanced startup after selecting it to boot from my grub screen

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, dell

I have dual boot system with ubuntu and windows. Both were working fine. On a recent windows update it was taking a lot of time to update so I forcefully shut down my dell laptop. Further when I restarted I was able to see the grub screen with both the operating systems. Ubuntu was working fine but when I tried booting windows it showed the message like "undoing the changes made to your computer" and then it restarts. To solve this problem I want to enter windows Advanced options, I think troubleshooting will help. However, I'm not able to enter the windows advanced options. When I restart my PC it first displays DELL and then I press F8 and F12 which takes me to the dell boot menu, it doesn't take me to the windows advanced options. How do I enter the windows advanced option in this case? When I start my pc it shows grub screen-> I select windows->it shows the black screen for sometime then it restarts and again shows the grub screen. I'm working on ubuntu currently, but how do I solve the windows problem?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/135509/how-would-i-boot-into-the-ubuntu-and-windows-recovery-modes-if-i-removed-the-opt useful?

Comment: I'm using windows 10. Pressing F8 key didn't work